# Using MongoDatabase class instead of MongoDatabaseImpl

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I need to set profiling level via Mongo C# Driver.

`Client.GetDatabase("test")` returns `IMongoDatabase` interface which resolves to `MongoDB.Driver.MongoDatabaseImpl` at runtime.

According to [MongoDB .NET Driver API Documentation](http://api.mongodb.com/csharp/current/html/M_MongoDB_Driver_MongoDatabase_SetProfilingLevel.htm) `MongoDatase` class has a `SetProfilingLevel` method which I can not cast to at runtime.

BTW I also installed Legacy Driver version 2.0.1 since [documentation](http://api.mongodb.com/csharp/current/html/M_MongoDB_Driver_MongoDatabase_SetProfilingLevel.htm) says that `SetProfilingLevel` method is in it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

New MongoDB driver (at least 2.3) doesn't have specific method for changing profiling level.
But you can execute any command using `RunCommandAsync`.

```
public async Task SetProfilingLevelAsync(IMongoDatabase database, int level)
{
    var command = new BsonDocumentCommand<BsonDocument>(new BsonDocument("profile", level));
    await database.RunCommandAsync(command);
}
```

Comment: You may want to add optional slowms parameter also.

Answer (score 3):

This method is indeed in legacy version of driver. So first intall legacy version and then:

```
var client = new MongoServer(new MongoServerSettings());
var db = client.GetDatabase("db_name");
db.SetProfilingLevel(ProfilingLevel.All);
```